# Eclipse IDE shows many terminals at startup. How clean it?

Tags: eclipse, terminal, appcelerator-studio

Every time I start Appcelerator Studio, IDE shows a lot of terminals at startup, like in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfS8h.png). Every time I close them all manually, but at the next startup it again shows the same terminals. Is there any configuration file that indicates which terminal load at startup? How is it possible to remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! The simple workaround would be to launch the studio in the new workspace, and import the projects from your old workspace to a new one.

However, if you have steps to reproduce this - please create a jira ticket here (https://jira.appcelerator.org/)

BTW, what version of studio are you using?

Comment: I had this problem already with Titanium, then also with Appcelerator Studio. Your suggestion helped me to better investigate. With a new workspace, in fact, the terminals do not appear. But I lose all run/debug/package configurations... after a bit of testing I was able to find the file in which the terminals are configured. This is the **workbench.xmi** file, located in .../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
You can remove the file, which is then recreated on the next sturtup. Or you can identify terminals tags and remove them :)